# Semantic use of <nav> in HTML5 with search form element

Tags: html, accessibility, semantics, nav, screen-readers

The W3C definition seems a bit vague when it comes to the [`<nav>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-nav-element) tag:

> The nav element represents a section of a page that links to other pages or to parts within the page: a section with navigation links.
>
> Not all groups of links on a page need to be in a nav element — the element is primarily intended for sections that consist of major navigation blocks. In particular, it is common for footers to have a short list of links to various pages of a site, such as the terms of service, the home page, and a copyright page. The footer element alone is sufficient for such cases; while a nav element can be used in such cases, it is usually unnecessary.
>
> User agents (such as screen readers) that are targeted at users who can benefit from navigation information being omitted in the initial rendering, or who can benefit from navigation information being immediately available, can use this element as a way to determine what content on the page to initially skip and/or provide on request.

Based on a very strict interpretation of their definition and what I've encountered through validation, it appears as though `<nav>` should only contain list elements. However, shouldn't search be considered a form of navigation within a series of pages?

While I understand that its primary use is for user agents, it still seems rather redundant to have a `<nav>` preceding a `<ul>` tag if the former acts only as a container for the latter. It would make more sense if `<nav>` could contain other elements related to navigation, not limited to a list of links.

For example:

```
<nav role="navigation">
  <form action="http://google.com/search" method="get">
    <fieldset role="search">
       <input type="hidden" name="q" value="site:mysite.com" />
       <input class="search" type="text" name="q" results="0" placeholder="Search"/>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <ul class="top-navigation">
     <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="/about.html">About Me</a></li>
     <li><a href="/archive.html">Archives</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Aside from validation, is this not an acceptable use of `<nav>`? What would the repercussions be for one less concerned with validation, than to ensure screen readers and other accessibility tools can render the page properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `nav` element should be used for main navigation items of the site, not just all navigation items. It also doesn't have to contain a `ul` but since most of the time it does contain a list, it often makes sense, but isn't essential.

If your search is the main navigtion method of your site, then by all means place it within a `nav`, although from the example you give above, the list appears to be the main navigation and not your search.

I've written a bit about using the `nav` tag at [to nav or not to nav?](http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2011/07/html5/to-nav-or-not-to-nav), although it doesn't mention a search, which is an interesting observation.

Comment: I like your interpretation a little bit better how I read the w3c spec. And while the search is not the main navigation method for my site, it is still a "major navigation block" in my opinion. 

With HTML5 in draft form I think I'm more concerned with how various user agents will interpret that block of code and how it might be optimized for such a purpose. That's the reason I included some of the ARIA roles as well. Hoping someone with more knowledge on that subject will chime in.

Thanks for your feedback though, very relieving to see that I'm not the only one concerned with this element.

Comment: If it is a major navigation block, then put it in a nav. None of the user agents do anything with it at the moment. With regards accessibility tools, I think that a search is better off being marked as a search (using the "search" landmark role). Plus you should only mark one element on a page with a "navigation" landmark role, so you should attach that to your list and "search" to the search. You can read more about these roles and some corresponding HTML5 elements (scroll down) at: http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2010/10/using-wai-aria-landmark-roles/

Comment: Thanks Ian. I took a look at the paciellogroup page, and the section on [`<nav>`] redirected me to [Bruce Lawson's site](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/). Looking at the source, he uses [`<nav>`] similar to how I have done. Defining the [`<nav>`] with role=navigation, and in his case the form element (as opposed to the fieldset element) with role=search. While I don't find either of these sites as a definitive enough authority on the subject, I will defer to them until I've had a chance to test my code on a couple accessibility tools and report back.

Comment: Ok, so I did quite a bit of testing and I'm happy to report that W3C has no problem validating a nav element that contains both a search form input and a list with links. Furthermore, it seems that as long as I use role=navigation for nav element, and role=search for the form element as opposed to the fieldset validator is happy. This would appear to be the best of both worlds. Thanks again Ian. I will likely write a blog post about what I've learned and will happily link to your blog as well.